# Remove Leading spaces of every index in ArrayList

Tags: java, regex, string, arraylist, java-8

So, everything is working fine except the trim function. I don't know if it's working or not.

Actually I am making an inverted index using ArrayList. Fetching lines from files, splitting into words (tokenizing) and removing punctuation. When I get to the part of removing stopwords it doesn't match with the stopwords provided in file. I think this is because of the leading space of every index of ArrayList.

StopWords List :

```
a, is, the, of, all, and, to, can, be, as, once, for, at, am, are, has, have, had, up, his, her, in, on, no, we, do
```

My Strategy:

```
String [] TempArray = new String[word.size()];

for (int i = 0; i < word.size(); i++) {
    word.set(i, word.get(i).toLowerCase());
    word.set(i, word.get(i).replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]", ""));
}   

for (int i = 0; i < word.size(); i++) {
    TempArray[i] = word.get(i);
    TempArray[i] = TempArray[i].trim();
    word.set(i, TempArray[i]);
    System.out.println(word.get(i));
}
```

Output:

```
[a, blunder, by, anton, chekhov, , an, illustration, for, the, story, a, blunder, by, the, author, anton, chekhov, portrait, of, ivan, lazhechnikov...]
```

Any kind of suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: That isn't the output of your program. It prints the words one per line. What is the actual output, and where are you removing stopwords?

Comment: The output shown above is through the statement `System.out.println(word);`

Comment: In that case, it doesn't indicate there are any leading spaces in your strings. That's just how List's toString method formats its output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
Arrays.stream(TempArray)
    .filter(s -> s != null)
    .map(String::trim)
    .toArray(String[]::new);
```

This creates the new array without leading or trailing spaces.

Comment: NullPointerException @Andronicus

Comment: @campaigner88 in this case Just after stream use `filter(s -> s != null)`

Comment: Thank you, I just added it :)

Comment: You could also use a method-reference for that: [`Objects.nonNull`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#nonNull-java.lang.Object-)

Comment: No need to create an array again. It could be done in place.

Comment: @oleg.cherednik no, because of `null`s - removing them changes the size of array

Comment: @campaigner88 my formula creates new array, the resulting one has no spaces

Comment: @campaigner88 if you still have spaces, then you have to filter non null or empty

Comment: That was mine. Modify a little your answer to make me able to remove downvoted.

Answer (score 0):

Just to extend a bit @Andronicus's answer, this will remove also empty strings from resulting array.

```
Arrays.stream(TempArray)
    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
    .map(String::trim)
    .filter(!String::isEmpty)
    .toArray(String[]::new);
```